# SSMA ProtectedStorage.ssma file being used by another process

Tags: sql-server-migration-assi

I am getting a repeated error trying to build the protected storage file for SSMA for Oracle version 6.0.1.  I have made various attempts; nothing works!  SSMA insists on writing to the roaming profile directory and the file it writes to is **ALWAYS** in use. Even if I reboot it is reported to be "in use."  Even if I power down and restart, it is reported to be in use.  Even when I use my home computer (which is configured with a local profile and where there is no place to roam), the application writes to the roaming profile and the file is reported to be in use.  It is the same with SSMA 5.3.  I also tried launching the special command shell with the same result.  It is the same with the 2012 server version.  I also tried using hardcoded values and skipping the variable file.

No one else reports this issue.  Does anyone know what am I doing wrong or how I can work around this issue?

Here is the command and error text:

```
C:\Windows\System32>SSMAforORacleConsole.exe -securepassword -add DEV -s "y:\dba\projects\OracleToSQLServerMigration\SSMAProjects\DEV_Migration\command-config\DataMigrationDEV.xml" -v y:\dba\projects\OracleToSQLServerMigration\SSMAProjects\DEV_Migration\command-config\VariableValueFileSample - DEV.xml"

[5/19/2016 10:32:33 AM]    INPUT Enter password for server id 'DEV': ****
[5/19/2016 10:32:36 AM]    INPUT Re-enter password for server id 'DEV': ****

[5/19/2016 10:32:38 AM] FATALERR Unexpected error during addition of servers to protected storage
[5/19/2016 10:32:38 AM]   **NESTED The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\amorris\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant\Oracle\ProtectedStorage.ssma' because it is being used by another process.**
```

Here is the connection file, DataMigrationDEV.xml (edited to remove server information):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  

-<ssma-script-file   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="..\Schemas\O2SSConsoleScriptSchema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">


-<config>


-<output-providers>

<data-migration-connection target-server="AAA_DEV" source-server="DEV"/>

<log-verbosity level="debug"/>

</output-providers>

</config>


-<servers>


-<sql-server name="AAA_DEV">


-<windows-authentication>

<server value="$SQLServerName$"/>

<database value="$SQLServerDb$"/>

<encrypt value="true"/>

<trust-server-certificate value="true"/>

</windows-authentication>

</sql-server>


-<oracle name="DEV">


-<tns-name-mode>

<connection-provider value="Oracle Client Provider"/>

<service-name value="$OracleInstance$"/>

<user-id value="$OracleUserName$"/>

</tns-name-mode>

</oracle>

</servers>


-<script-commands>

<connect-source-database server="DEV"/>

<connect-target-database server="AAA_DEV"/>

<map-schema sql-server-schema="$SQLServerDb$.dbo" source-   schema="$OracleSchemaName$"/>

<migrate-data verbose="true" report-errors="true" write-summary-report-    to="$SummaryReports$" object-type="category" object-name="$OracleSchemaName$.Tables"/>

</script-commands>

</ssma-script-file>
```

Here is the variable file (edited to remove identifying information):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
        Variable value file for SSMA-v4.2 Console for Oracle adapted for AIMS.
        Specified name and value attribute values are mandatory
        Name values should begin and end with '$'
        Use of this file is NOT mandatory
        option -v[ariable]. See the documentation for SSMA-v4.2 Console for  more information.
-->
<variables xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="..\Schemas\ConsoleScriptVariablesSchema.xsd">
  <!--
      ********************************** MUST DO **************************************************
      ***** MUST replace occurrences of {<value>} with appropriate values wherever necessary  *****
           *********************************************************************************************
  -->

  <!--
        ***************************************************************************
        ***** The "working folder" {Working Folder Path} should exist         *****
        ***** prior to console script execution                               *****
            ***************************************************************************
    -->
  <variable name="$WorkingFolder$"      value="d:\app\OracleToSQLServerMigration\DEV_Migration\"/>

  <variable-group name="OracleConnection">
    <variable name="$OracleInstance$"  value="DEV"/>
    <variable name="$OracleUserName$"  value="USERA"/>
    <variable name="$OraclePassword$"  value="{password}"/>
    <variable name="$OracleSchemaName$" value="SCHEMAA"/>
 </variable-group>

  <variable-group name="SQLServerConnection">
    <variable name="$SQLServerName$"   value="dev.sample.edu\DEV"/>
    <variable name="$SQLServerDb$"     value="MigrationTest"/>
  </variable-group>

  <variable-group name="Report">
    <variable name="$SummaryReports$"               value="$WorkingFolder$"/>
    <variable name="$AssessmentReportFolderName$"   value="AssessmentReports"/>
    <variable name="$AssessmentReports$"               value="$WorkingFolder$\$AssessmentReportFolderName$"/>
     <variable name="$RefreshDBFolder$"              value="$WorkingFolder$"/>
    <variable name="$ConvertARReportsFolder$"           value="$WorkingFolder$\$AssessmentReportFolderName$"/>
    <variable name="$SynchronizationReports$"       value="$WorkingFolder$"/>
    <variable name="$SaveScriptFolder$"             value="$WorkingFolder$"/>
    <variable name="$ConvertSQLReports$"            value="$WorkingFolder$"/>
    <!--
        ***************************************************************************
        ***** The folder {Folder where sql files are stored} needs to exists  ***** 
        ***** and should contain the *.sql files that need to be converted    *****
        ***** using convert-sql-statement command                             *****
        ***************************************************************************
    -->
    <variable name="$ConvertSqlSampleFiles$"        value="$WorkingFolder$\   {Folder where sql files are stored}"/>
  </variable-group>

  <variable-group name="ProjectSpecs">
    <variable name="$project_name$" value="DEV_Migration"/>
    <variable name="$project_overwrite$" value="true"/>
    <variable name="$project_type$" value="sql-server-2014"/>
    <variable name="$project_folder$" value="$WorkingFolder$\$project_name$"/>
  </variable-group>

</variables>
```

I have been through some web pages for *file used by another process* errors.  I just do not see how the file could be used by another process.  It gets created by this application!  And the repetition on all servers makes a legitimate error or any kind of server permission error less likely.

Any ideas?

Thank you,
A L Morris

Comment: I traced the process with ProcessMonitor.  Process 28084 creates the file, queries it for network information, closes it, creates it, opens it for standard information, reads it, reads it again, gets the end of file, creates it again gets a sharing violation and closes it.

Comment: Time of Day","Process Name","PID","Operation","Path","Result","Detail"
"4:13:45.9852398 PM","SSMAforOracleConsole.exe","28084","CreateFile","C:\Users\a.aaa.amorris\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant\Oracle\ProtectedStorage.ssma","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened"

Comment: "4:13:45.9853277 PM","SSMAforOracleConsole.exe","28084","QueryNetworkOpenInformationFile","C:\Users\a.aaa.amorris\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant\Oracle\ProtectedStorage.ssma","SUCCESS","CreationTime: 6/7/2016 3:56:19 PM, LastAccessTime: 6/7/2016 3:56:19 PM, LastWriteTime: 6/7/2016 3:56:19 PM, ChangeTime: 6/7/2016 4:12:32 PM, AllocationSize: 48, EndOfFile: 41, FileAttributes: ANCI"

Comment: "4:13:45.9853686 PM","SSMAforOracleConsole.exe","28084","CloseFile","C:\Users\a.aaa.amorris\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant\Oracle\ProtectedStorage.ssma","SUCCESS",""

Comment: "4:13:45.9875299 PM","SSMAforOracleConsole.exe","28084","CreateFile","C:\Users\a.aaa.amorris\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant\Oracle\ProtectedStorage.ssma","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Open No Recall, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened"

Comment: "4:13:45.9876258 PM","SSMAforOracleConsole.exe","28084","QueryStandardInformationFile","C:\Users\a.aaa.amorris\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant\Oracle\ProtectedStorage.ssma","SUCCESS","AllocationSize: 48, EndOfFile: 41, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False"

Comment: "4:13:45.9876990 PM","SSMAforOracleConsole.exe","28084","ReadFile","C:\Users\a.aaa.amorris\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant\Oracle\ProtectedStorage.ssma","SUCCESS","Offset: 0, Length: 41, Priority: Normal"

Comment: "4:13:45.9878327 PM","SSMAforOracleConsole.exe","28084","ReadFile","C:\Users\a.aaa.amorris\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant\Oracle\ProtectedStorage.ssma","END OF FILE","Offset: 41, Length: 41"

Comment: "4:13:45.9882015 PM","SSMAforOracleConsole.exe","28084","CreateFile","C:\Users\a.aaa.amorris\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant\Oracle\ProtectedStorage.ssma","SHARING VIOLATION","Desired Access: Generic Write, Read Attributes, Disposition: OverwriteIf, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Open No Recall, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, AllocationSize: 0"

Comment: I think this is a bug and that the process itself is closing the file in the wrong order.